# Removing OpenSSL 3.0 devel so C++ compiles on Linux

Tags: c++, linux, cmake, openssl

I'm on Ubuntu 22.04 and compiling this C++ Github pull request:

https://github.com/ftexchange/ftx/pull/13

However, the PR contains a compile error.

Somebody posted to fix the error OpenSSL 3.0 devel version must be "removed":

> It seems like the compiler was using OpenSSL 3.0 devel version, I had
> to remove that

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Do you know how to use `apt remove`? Although it is unlikely to fix the compilation error. Without any more info to go on, I surmise that the code in question is incompatible with OpenSSL 3. If so, removing the 3.0 devel package is just half the story.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik That was part of my confusion. Do they mean remove OpenSSL 3 and install OpenSSL 1 etc. I think the underlying issue was name collisions.

Comment: That would be my interpretation.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.

```
$ sudo apt install libboost-dev libssl-dev
$ git clone --recursive --branch openssl-1.1 https://github.com/arf-labs-ou/ftx.git
$ cmake -G Ninja -S ftx/cpp -B build -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
$ cmake --build build
```

Trying to build at this point will trip deprecation warnings when compiling against the system OpenSSL 3. But because `ftx` has done the ***extremely inadvisable*** thing of hard-coding `-Werror` in their build, this is promoted to a spurious error. Deprecated doesn't mean "won't work today"; it means "upstream must fix". You are not upstream, so this ought not affect you, but, alas, low-quality build code is not a great surprise.

We will hack around this by wrapping the compiler with a shell script that deletes warning flags from the command line. Create a file called `no-warnings.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

ARGS=()

for arg in "$@"; do
  if [[ ! "$arg" =~ ^-W ]]; then
    ARGS+=("$arg")
  fi
done

"${ARGS[@]}"
```

Now let's inject it into the build via the `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_LAUNCHER` hook:

```
$ chmod +x no-warnings.sh
$ rm -rf build
$ cmake -G Ninja -S ftx/cpp/ -B build -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_LAUNCHER=$PWD/no-warnings.sh
$ cmake --build build/
```

This *should* work but, unfortunately, even this wasn't enough to build successfully. The code itself has a type error! I wonder if something changed between Boost 1.71 and 1.74. Anyway, I applied the following patch:

```
diff --git a/cpp/src/util/HTTP.cc b/cpp/src/util/HTTP.cc
index 30e0277..2d043f2 100644
--- a/cpp/src/util/HTTP.cc
+++ b/cpp/src/util/HTTP.cc
@@ -100,8 +100,8 @@ void HTTPSession::authenticate(http::request<http::string_body>& req)
     std::string path(req.target());
     std::string body(req.body());
 
-    long ts = get_ms_timestamp(current_time()).count();
-    std::string data = std::to_string(ts) + method + path;
+    auto ts = std::to_string(get_ms_timestamp(current_time()).count());
+    std::string data = ts + method + path;
     if (!body.empty()) {
         data += body;
     }
```

And *now* the above commands produce a successful build. The example programs run and produce reasonable output, as well.