# How to add and remove some flag to cmake in commandline?

Tags: cmake, linker, hhvm

In the command line ubuntu, I want to directly delete a series of flags contained in the source code of the HHVM when using cmake for install HHVM, if available, and add another set of flags to it.
What should I do about this?
please guide me.

for use linker -Wl,--emit-relocs  should don't use -E , -s and -c.

example :

$ cmake  + (-O3 -fno-reorder-blocks-and-partition -Wl,--emit-relocs)

and

$ cmake - (-E ,-s,-c)

Comment: You ought to be able to add flags by setting `CMAKE_{C,CXX}_FLAGS` at the CMake command line. Removing flags is a lot harder if the project doesn't give you a way to do it. You might want to create a wrapper shell script [like in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72751107/2137996) to drop the bad flags from the command line. You can inject such a script via `CMAKE_{C,CXX}_COMPILER_LAUNCHER`.